# Configure ethernet interface to accept unidirectional ethernet

Tags: networking, ethernet, network-interface

With switches you can configure an ethernet port to be [unidirectional](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst4500/12-2/54sg/configuration/guide/config/unieth.pdf). This gives you the ability to double your traffic capabilities.

Can I configure my ethernet interface on a unix system to read traffic from both RX and TX signals instead of reserving half for transmission? How?

Will setting my interface in promiscuous mode enable my interface to read all packets from both RX and TX?

How can I configure a unix based system to read both TX and RX?

Answer (score 0):

Unidirectional ethernet is actually something else entirely. You are asking about full-duplex ethernet vs. half-duplex ethernet.

Most modern ethernet ports support auto-detection for things like speed and duplex, and will negotiate the fastest speed, and full duplex (if available). Negotiation is optional in 10BASE-T and 100BASE-TX, but mandatory in 1000BASE-T.

Alternatively, you can set fixed speed and duplex on a port, but this is not recommended, and, since auto-negotiation is a requirement for 1000BASE-T, some vendors have opted to remove the ability to fix settings for that speed.

The reason you shouldn't mess with the speed and duplex setting has to do with the default duplex settings for 10BASE-T and 100BASE-TX. Both 10BASE-T and 100BASE-TX have a default of half duplex. When on side of a link is set to fixed settings, negotiation is disabled, and the other side can detect (not negotiate) the speed, but the duplex will be set at the default, half-duplex rate. This results in one side set to full duplex, and the other side at half duplex. This causes serious problems with the link, slowing the transfer rate to a crawl.

This isn't a problem for 1000BASE-T since the default duplex is full. In fact, when the standard for 1000BASE-T was debated, there was a large contingent of engineers who wanted to completely eliminate half duplex from the standard. Unfortunately, half duplex was left in, but the standard for 10GBASE-T finally eliminated the half-duplex option.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I realize this is a scattered question, and am unsure how to phrase it. My understanding is that full duplex is the ability to use some wires of the ethernet cord for transmission while the others are reserved for receiving in parallel. I also assumed that half-duplex is like a walkie talky but still will only use half of the wires/pins in an ethernet cord but will wait for transmission. What I'm ultimately trying to get at is, can I tell my network interface to only read data/packets from the full wire, instead of reserving half/4 for transmission.

Comment: The way ethernet works, when one host want to send to another, it will need to resolve the layer-3 address to the layer-2 address, and it uses ARP to send a broadcast request for the layer-2 address. The host with that layer-2 address will respond, and the sending host can now create an ethernet frame with the MAC address of the receiving host. Switches also learn which ports have which MAC addresses connected from the traffic coming into the port. With a receive-only  host, this is broken. There are specialty security devices which do unidirectional, but they are not appropriate for most use.

Comment: Ron, thank you for your response. I agree with communication it would be broken. For my particular use case I am only trying to listen/tap into a network. The core of what I'm trying to is listen to as much as possible.

Comment: How will any other host know to send to your host if your host cannot provide a MAC address? Maybe you mean something like SPAN where all the traffic from one or more ports or VLANs is sent to a port. This is configured on the switch, but it doesn't change the way ethernet or cabling is used. Even the (expensive) security devices for unidirectional ethernet only use a single pair for 10BASE-T or 100BASE-TX (1000BASE-T uses two pairs in each direction).

Comment: It's a tap with the network interface in promiscuous mode. Currently, I have a switch mirroring everything on a port and sending it to an IDS, I wanted to explore other options. Without getting into unrelated details I just wanted to know if it's possible to only listen to all wires of an ethernet connection. Read only.

Comment: Why? That doesn't gain anything. The switch can't send on all wires, and the end-device can't listen on all wires. That wouldn't be in _any_ ethernet standard. 10BASE-T and 100-BASETX use one pair for each directions, while 1000BASE-T and 10GBASE-T use two pairs for each direction. The ethernet hardware in the switch and the host is built to the standards.

Comment: Okay thanks, that's all I was looking for...if is it possible to listen to all wires, and it looks like it's not.